# Cannot print/find the number of records mongo_db with go

Tags: go, mongo-go

```
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"

func count() int{
     collection := client.Database("thepolyglotdeveloper").Collection("people")
    filter := bson.M{"sig": bson.M{ "$eq": "sdfsdf" }}//iv.Sig
    cur,_ := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
    count,_ := collection.Count(context.TODO(), filter)
    return count
}

func main(){
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    client, _ = mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    .....
}
```

The error received:-

```
# command-line-arguments
./example.go:131:23: collection.Count undefined (type *mongo.Collection has no field or method Count)
```

I believe that I am not using the correct method for the count. I am using it to find out is there any record the preexists with the filter in the database. Please suggest.

```
count,_ := collection.Count(context.TODO(), filter)
```

Is it the correct usage.

Comment: I found this function signature in their source code `// CountDocuments gets the number of documents matching the filter.
// For a fast count of the total documents in a collection see EstimatedDocumentCount. 
func (coll *Collection) CountDocuments(ctx context.Context, filter interface{},
 opts ...*options.CountOptions) (int64, error) {
...` Maybe there is not Count menthod but an CountDocuments

Answer (score 1):

EstimatedDocumentCount and CountDocuments are the methods used to get the number of documents in the collection.

Refer General documentation for the MongoDB Go Driver to find out the available functions:

https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo